# Anyone know the reason and how go fix it? Android Studio 1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

```
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.luogaugrong.mrluo.myapplication
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

Answer (score 1):

`INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK` is because your `minSdkVersion` is higher than the API level of the device or emulator you are trying to run your app on. For example, if your `minSdkVersion` is set to 23, it will only run on Android 6.0 and higher devices.

You will find your `minSdkVersion` probably in your `app/` module's `build.gradle` file, or possibly in a `<uses-sdk>` element in your `ApplicationManifest.xml` file.